# Linq C# Join tables if value of two fields exists in another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables that I want to join using a linq query

Table 1 called activities has the following fields
ID
Code
Description

Table 2 named pred has the following fields
task_id
pred_task_id
pred_type

I want the linq query to join both tables and returns values if and only if both task_id and pred_task_id exists in Table 1.ID

I had a stab at it with no success

```
from pre in pred.AsEnumerable()
join act in activities.AsEnumerable()
on pre.Field<string>("task_id") equals act.Id
where (pre.Field<string>("task_id") == activity.Id)
select new
{
    Pred = getTaskbyID(pre.Field<string>("pred_task_id"), activities),
    Succ = getTaskbyID(pre.Field<string>("task_id"),activities),
    RelationshipType = pre.Field<string>("pred_type")

});
```

This code does not execute what I am aiming to achieve. It returns list of all activities if the pred.task_id exist in activities.id. I want to make another filter to ensure that pred.pred_task_id also exists in the activities table.

Comment: Make another `join` to `activities` on pred.pred_task_id?

Comment: If you're making that JOIN, won't `pre.Field<string>("task_id")` *already equal* `activity.Id`?

Comment: I have tried adding another join which did not resulted in achieving my objectives.

Comment: Robert,
Yes the join will make task_id equal to activity.Id but what I want to achieve is a bit different. I want to join tables is the above condition is met and if pred_task_id which is another field values exist in activity.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `where` clause:

```
where activities.Any(a=> a.Id == pre.Field<string>("pred_task_id"))
```

Comment: Mark,
I have tried it and your code is working exactly as it is expected to perform. Many thanks